# How to update only last record of SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite database in android. I need to update the record based on some condition. But there are multiple records that fulfills the condition, so all records are getting updated. I need to update only last one. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
 public void UPDATE_INVOICE(int invoice_id,int owner_id,int vehicle_id,String invoice_date,String invoice_time,String dest,String distance,String validity_date, int qty,String local_var)
 {
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(INVOICE_NUMBER, invoice_id);

            values.put(INVOICE_DATE, invoice_date);
            values.put(INVOICE_TIME, invoice_time);


            values.put(INVOICE_VALIDITY_DATE, validity_date);
            values.put(INVOICE_QTY, qty);
            values.put(INVOICE_LOCAL, local_var);

            db.update(TABLE_INVOICE_DETAILS, values, INVOICE_OWNER_ID_REF+"="+owner_id+" and "+INVOICE_VEHICLE_ID_REF+"="+vehicle_id, new String[]{});


        }
```

Comment: Add one more column to db for the time when row has been added to db. Now you will have a unique key to identify the last inserted row in all...

Comment: OK. I will try it out

Comment: This is not how databases work.  if there is a concept of "a last row", then there must be columns which determine which one is the last row.  Last row makes no sense without them.

Comment: Does this table have some `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column?

Answer (score 0):

If someone else will find that question, then possible answer is:

```
update table1 set last_accessed_dt = datetime('now') where _id = (SELECT MAX(_id) FROM table1);
```